# Error java.lang.InstantiationException

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, persistence.xml

I'm trying to create a project with glassfish JSF and JPA, but I'm having trouble with the persistence unit in the persistence.xml file.

The error is the following:

GlassFish 3.1 at localhost

> 2014-05-06T12:47:52.326-0300|INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.6
>   (SNAPSHOT 20111206) for context '/K19-Integracao-JSF-JPA'
>   2014-05-06T12:47:52.649-0300|SEVERE:
>   WebModule[/K19-Integracao-JSF-JPA]PWC1270: Exception starting filter
>   br.com.k19.filters.JPAFilter java.lang.InstantiationException     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:124)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5377)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2018)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
>     at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
>     at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for
>   EntityManager named k19pu     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown
>   Source)   at br.com.k19.filters.JPAFilter.init(JPAFilter.java:57)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:120)
>     ... 41 more
>
> 2014-05-06T12:47:52.662-0300|INFO: WEB0671: Loading application
>   [K19-Integracao-JSF-JPA] at [/K19-Integracao-JSF-JPA]
>   2014-05-06T12:47:52.693-0300|INFO: K19-Integracao-JSF-JPA was
>   successfully deployed in 774 milliseconds.
>   2014-05-06T12:47:53.049-0300|SEVERE: Error Rendering
>   View[/carros.xhtml] javax.el.ELException: /carros.xhtml @24,58
>   rendered="#{not empty carroBean.carros}":
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:413)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1751)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   br.com.k19.modelo.CarroRepository.buscaTodos(CarroRepository.java:21)
>     at br.com.k19.controle.CarroBean.getCarros(CarroBean.java:30)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)   at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)    at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstEmpty.getValue(AstEmpty.java:66)     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:63)     at
>   com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     ... 35 more
>
> 2014-05-06T12:47:53.053-0300|WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces
>   Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw
>   exception java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   br.com.k19.modelo.CarroRepository.buscaTodos(CarroRepository.java:21)
>     at br.com.k19.controle.CarroBean.getCarros(CarroBean.java:30)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)   at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)    at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstEmpty.getValue(AstEmpty.java:66)     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:63)     at
>   com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:413)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1751)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

---

And the classes I am using are as follows:

```
package br.com.k19.modelo;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public class CarroRepository {

    private EntityManager manager;

    public CarroRepository(EntityManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public void adiciona(Carro carro) {
        this.manager.persist(carro);
    }

    public  List<Carro> buscaTodos() {
        Query query = this.manager.createQuery("select x from Carro x");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

---

```
package br.com.k19.modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Carro implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4209908627808946183L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }
    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }
    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }
    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }
    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }   
}
```

---

```
package br.com.k19.filters;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;


@WebFilter(servletNames={"Faces Servlet"})
public class JPAFilter implements Filter {

    private EntityManagerFactory factory;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

        this.factory.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // Chegada
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
        request.setAttribute("EntityManager", manager);
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        // Chegada

        // Faces Servelet
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        // Faces Servelet

        // Saída
        try {
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            manager.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
        // Saída

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        this.factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("K19-PU");
    }
}
```

---

```
package br.com.k19.controle;

import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import br.com.k19.modelo.Carro;
import br.com.k19.modelo.CarroRepository;

@ManagedBean
public class CarroBean {

    private Carro carro = new Carro();

    public void adicionaCarro() {
        EntityManager manager = this.getEntityManager();
        CarroRepository repository = new CarroRepository(manager);

        repository.adiciona(carro);
        carro = new Carro();
    }

    public List<Carro> getCarros() {
        EntityManager manager = this.getEntityManager();
        CarroRepository repository = new CarroRepository(manager);
        return repository.buscaTodos();
    }

    private EntityManager getEntityManager() {

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest();
        EntityManager manager = (EntityManager) request.getAttribute("EntityManager");

        return manager;
    }

    public Carro getCarro() {
        return carro;
    }

    public void setCarro(Carro carro) {
        this.carro = carro;
    }
}
```

---

And the file carro.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 

<h:head>
    <title>K19 treinamentos</title>
</h:head> 
<h:body> 
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">

            <h:outputLabel value="Marca: " for="campo-marca" />
            <h:inputText value="#{carroBean.carro.marca}" id="campo-marca" />

            <h:outputLabel value="Modelo: " for="campo-modelo" />
            <h:inputText value="#{carroBean.carro.modelo}" id="campo-modelo" />

            <h:commandButton action="#{carroBean.adicionaCarro}" value="Adicionar" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty carroBean.carros}" >
        <h1>Lista de Carros</h1>

        <ul>
            <ui:repeat value="#{carroBean.carros}" var="carro">
                <li> <h:outputText value="#{carro.marca} #{carro.modelo}" /> </li>
            </ui:repeat>
        </ul>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:body> 
</html>
```

---

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="K19-PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/K19DB"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

My persistence.xml in this folder: ~/workspace/K19-Integracao-JSF-JPA/src/META-INF/persistence.xml

I put the mysql connector jar in the glassfish directory: 
/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar

I'm sorry for posting so much, is that I'm already crazy with this error.

I already searched a lot on the internet and can not resolve the problem, please can someone help me?

Comment: Some parts of the code has words in Portuguese but I think this is irrelevant to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think should always look at the root cause of exception. In your case

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
No Persistence provider for EntityManager named k19pu at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory
```

Your `persistence.xml` is not valid that's why `EntityManagerFactory` can't be get created.

due this you are also getting NLP at `CarroRepository#buscaTodos` method

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at br.com.k19.modelo.CarroRepository.buscaTodos
```

So Please correct your Persistence.xml and make sure same PU. hope this will solve your problem

Comment: <persistence-unit name="K19-PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> 

...
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
   this.factory =
   Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("K19-PU");
}
...

The PU in persistence.xml is what I'm using in JPAFilter class, and does not work anyway, since yesterday I to rolling google looking for a solution!


Not generating any table in MySql is why the NullPointerException happens, but I do not know why it does not generate the table!

Comment: before NullPointerException , you are getting No Persistence provider for EntityManager at br.com.k19.filters.JPAFilter.init(JPAFilter.java:57)

Comment: Have you added the hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0-GA.jar  and core because NetBean uses the EclipseLink

Comment: Yes! I know that, but do not know why! The mysql jar is in the Glassfish lib folder.

Comment: @Patterson Silva You have two one form javax.persistence.* packages from eclipselinks jar and other from hibernate, so please remove eclipselink.jar from classpath

Comment: Thank you very much! @user35736644892 you asked if I had added the hibernate-3.4.0-entitymanager-GA.jar. So I had not added the tutorial I followed said nothing, spoke only to put the mysql jar! So I put the entitymanager-hibernate-3.4.0-GA.jar then generated a new exception: ClassNotFoundException.

So I copied the other's jar of Hibernate required folder and pasted in the glassfish lib, and now it works!

Again thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

> 2014-05-06T12:47:53.049-0300|SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/carros.xhtml] javax.el.ELException: /carros.xhtml @24,58 rendered="#{not empty carroBean.carros}": java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at br.com.k19.modelo.CarroRepository.buscaTodos(CarroRepository.java:21) at br.com.k19.controle.CarroBean.getCarros(CarroBean.java:30)

Looking until `CarroRepository#buscaTodos`, line 21 of CarroRepository.java: file, we get this line:

```
Query query = this.manager.createQuery("select x from Carro x");
```

The `NullPointerException` means that `EntityManager manager` is `null`.

You have to check why the `EntityManagerFactory` cannot create a new instance of `EntityManager` in your `JPAFilter` servlet filter.

Comment: The hibernate does not generate  carro entity in mysql and it is strange because the mysql jar is in the correct folder!I think that is why it generates a NullPointer Exception in JPAFilter class. And I do not know how to solve.

Comment: @PattersonSilva do not trust on Hibernate or the ORM framework to create the tables for you. Consider creating the tables yourself.

Comment: Yes I understand, but should work, I wanted to know why does not work!
I followed a tutorial, but do not post here that is in portuguese!

Comment: @PattersonSilva wait for a JPA expert that can help you on that. I'm just trying to help you to solve this current problem. IMO that should be another question in this site.